# PDF DroidReader

Tags: android

i am trying to use DroidReader to get a view of my pdf file in my android.
i importe well the app and got no error, but when i lunch it, i got this error:

```
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at de.hilses.droidreader.DroidReaderActivity.onCreate(DroidReaderActivity.java:108)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load pdfrender: findLibrary returned null
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    at de.hilses.droidreader.PdfRender.<clinit>(PdfRender.java:111)
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355):    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1):

See this line:

```
02-27 21:15:25.433: E/AndroidRuntime(11355): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load pdfrender: findLibrary returned null
```

You need ***pdfrender*** library in you *classpath*

Answer (score 0):

Application cannot find the native library it is looking for. If you have the sources for the native code you can do an ndk-build before running the app. This should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Download the source code here ([Display PDF file inside my android application](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/02/15/display-pdf-file-inside-my-android-application/))

**activity_main.xml**

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="40dp"
>     android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
>     android:text="View PDF"
>     android:textColor="#ffffff"
>     android:id="@+id/tv_header"
>     android:textSize="18dp"
>     android:gravity="center"></TextView>
>
> <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
>     android:id="@+id/pdfView"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/tv_header"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
>
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

**MainActivity.java**
    package pdfviewer.pdfviewer;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnPageChangeListener,OnLoadCompleteListener{
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "android_tutorial.pdf";
PDFView pdfView;
Integer pageNumber = 0;
String pdfFileName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    pdfView= (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
}

private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
    pdfFileName = assetFileName;

    pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
            .defaultPage(pageNumber)
            .enableSwipe(true)

            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .onPageChange(this)
            .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
            .onLoad(this)
            .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
            .load();
}


@Override
public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
    pageNumber = page;
    setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
}


@Override
public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
    PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
    printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

}

public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
    for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

        Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

        if (b.hasChildren()) {
            printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
        }
    }
}

}
```